# Online multiplayer command line game with RPi as server

Tags: c#, server, raspberry-pi, console-application

I've been learning to code C# Console Applications and to take it a step further would like to get into server based stuff. I thought a good simple way to do this would be to make a text based console game but online, just something turn based where each player waits to input. Since I have an old Pi laying around, I thought that would be a good option for the server.

Everything I find by searching though is much more complicated, usually a Unity game or JavaScript browser game. I just want to get used to the absolute basics of setting up a server and interacting with it from as scratch as possible.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: This will probably be closed since it's not the right place for it (opinion based), but check this link out: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=157724

Comment: The best answer probably depends on how low-level you're trying to get. Are you looking to learn to poke data to a raw socket?